# Installing Apache Mesos on CentOS or RHEL

Tags: centos, apache-mesos

I tried to install the latest release tarball of Mesos on CentOS 6.4 with no luck. It ended up in all sorts of failures in trying to find jvm & jni bindings. Is there any instructions on how to install Mesos on RHEL or CentOS ?

Comment: You might want to check out the [mesosphere getting started for rpm based installations](http://mesosphere.io/docs/mesosphere/getting-started/rpm-install/).

Comment: It's been a while since you have posted that question but so newcomers, there are some installation instructions here: http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/ for Ubuntu 14.04, Mac OS X Yosemite & El Capitan, CentOS 6.6 and CentOS 7.1. It can be a good start even if you don't have those OS versions.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any instructions around so I thought I would troubleshoot all through my way and thought of documenting it here so it can save your time.

First things first, load your CentOS box with essential build tools to get started

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

Get Java and python dependencies installed

```
$ sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64  java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 python python-devel libcurl libcurl-devel
```

Get the latest Mesos tarball

```
$ wget http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/apache/mesos/0.13.0/mesos-0.13.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf mesos-0.13.0.tar.gz
$ cd mesos-0.13.0
```

Before you can build Mesos, you need to set correct JAVA binding paths

```
$ export  JAVA_HOME=/usr
$ export  JAVA_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/jre/lib/amd64/server -R/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm"
$ export  JAVA_CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/include/linux"
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/jre/lib/amd64/server:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Configure and build it

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

After you have built Mesos, it is advisable that you build and run the tests, this will make sure that what you have installed meets all the requirements

```
$ make check
```

If the checks are successful, You are just one step away from installing it in your system installation paths

```
$ make install
```

To learn how to use Mesos , go here http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

I hope you found this useful and saved your time troubleshooting it.

Comment: Having the same problems on Ubuntu.  Have you been able to get an external slave to connect to the master?